# Claudia.js NetworkingError creating Lambda Function - Times out after 120000ms

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, timeout, claudia.js

I've built a bot using the claudia.js [claudia-bot-builder](https://claudiajs.com/claudia-bot-builder.html) and all was working fine until I tried to push an update this morning. Now the script is timing out.

**Script**

```
claudia create --region ap-southeast-2 --api-module index --profile xero-messenger-bot
```

**Error**

```
creating Lambda lambda.createFunction   FunctionName=my-bot
{TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 120000ms
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/claudia/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:83:34)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:186:7)
    at TLSSocket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:679:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:186:7)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:342:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
  message: 'Connection timed out after 120000ms',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  time: 2017-04-20T05:48:18.230Z,
  region: 'ap-southeast-2',
  hostname: 'lambda.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true 
}
```

I've tried a few different regions (ap-southeast-1, us-east-2 etc) but they all seem to throw the same error.

I'd think it was my code, but this same script was working yesterday, so I'm not sure why it isn't today.

Any ideas where to check for more information?

Comment: Have you tried to increase timeout to 5 minutes? I got my problem solved with that, because I had unreliable internet connection.

Comment: Yes. That was 100% correct. It was a flakey connection that was dropping packets and causing the issue. Worked fine when I ran the same script at work.

Comment: I tried this way: claudia create --handler lambda.handler  --timeout 300. It is not working !

Answer (score 4):

After too much searching about I stop by Gitter's [Claudia's](https://gitter.im/claudiajs/claudia).  @stojanovic suggest to me that I should use **--use-s3-bucket** flag.

```
claudia create --handler lambda.handler --use-s3-bucket your-bucket-name --deploy-proxy-api --region us-east-1
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go. I ended up deploying an EC2 instance in Sydney and installed git and Claudia there. Then after I've tested locally I check in to git. Log in to the remote terminal and run Claudia update from there. Has worked fine so far. Still not sure why my home internet has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old post but a quick nasty fix can be just going to NPM global claudia package  and edit the following file _~\node_modules\claudia\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\http\node.js_ and add the timeout that works for you:

```
...
AWS.NodeHttpClient = AWS.util.inherit({
  handleRequest: function handleRequest(httpRequest, httpOptions, callback, errCallback) {
      httpOptions.timeout = xxxxx (default to 120000);
...
```

Hope that helps